# Generate API and Data Model java files from Open API Generator with maven plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using maven plugin of openapi generator (not swagger code generator) but the java files are not getting generated as yaml file has $ref relative paths.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Docs/Project/xxxxyy/workspace1/MnS-Rel-16/MnS-Rel-16/OpenAPI/provMnS.yaml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <modelPackage>com.xxx.xxx.dto.etsi.moi</modelPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My yaml file has $ref in many places. Example below.

```
            schema:
                $ref: 'comDefs.yaml#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'
```

Getting below exception:

```
[WARNING] Exception while resolving:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1967)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefToExternalSchema (ExternalRefProcessor.java:113)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefSchema (ExternalRefProcessor.java:921)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processSchema (ExternalRefProcessor.java:200)
```

So how to generate the server code (spring) with Open API Generator with yaml file having $ref?

Comment: Can you share the yaml file so we can help ?

Comment: Sure. Here it is, https://forge.3gpp.org/rep/sa5/MnS/raw/6fa5a08805fcf5bf783030838a0f1a17317dc39d/OpenAPI/provMnS.yaml

Also you will get the open source project where all the relative files ($ref) are there
 https://forge.3gpp.org/rep/sa5/MnS/blob/Rel-16/OpenAPI/provMnS.yaml

Comment: the first link you shared has no issue and its was generated successfully with me , and in the second link the usage is correct as there is a file called comDefs in the same folder as provMnS.yaml , am i missing something ?

Comment: So are you able to generate the model classes with the first link? How have you done it. Can you please share the maven plugin code and guide me. As I was not able to generate code with first link.
Because in the first link also there is reference to other yaml file as well.
- anyOf:
            - $ref: 'genericNrm.yaml#/components/schemas/resources-genericNrm'

Comment: am sorry i tried with gradle , just added the four yaml files next to the one with the first link and it worked with no error given .

Comment: @George, So you are saying you have replaced the relative paths of the referenced yaml with full path? Or just keeping those referenced file in the same folder of main yaml file worked? Can you please share the gradle code so that I can check once. Thanks for helping me out.